# How to access method in outer classes in java?

Tags: java, class, nested, outer-join

I have classes like:

```
 class myClass1 {
   public void test() {};

 class myClass2 {

  public void test() {};
 class myClass3 {
    test();
....................
 } } }
```

How to be sure that method test from myClass 1 but not from myClass2?
Thanks.

Comment: To be sure to invoke the correct test method, just insert few lines of System.out.println() on the test method implementation, e.g. in test of myClass1: System.out.println("this is the main test method from myclass1"), and invoke the methods just as you are used to.

Answer (score 6):

```
myClass1.this.test();
```

BTW, it is an extremely strong convention in Java to start class names with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

Just do `myClass1.this.test();`

Answer (score 2):

Access the outer instances with the following syntax:

`myClass1.this.test()`

`myClass2.this.test()`

Then it is unambigious.

Note: As others have noted correctly `myClass1` with a small `m` is a bad class name. So in the above code sample it looks like I access an instance of `myClass1` at first glance but in fact I am accessing the *class* to get the current enclosing instance. This would be obvious when following the naming conventions: `MyClass1.this` returns that specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling an object, it will always be the method from the object's class:

```
MyClass2 testObject = new MyClass2();
testObject.test(); // calls method from MyClass2
```

If your methods are static, you'll have to specify the class when calling:

```
MyClass2.test();
```

Or if you have a `MyClass3` object and want want to call `MyClass1#test()`:

```
MyClass1.this.test(); 
// will run the method from MyClass1, even if its a MyClass3 object
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make an object of myClass1 to call this method. You cannot directly call methods until class2 is not extending class1.

```
myClass1 obj = new myClass1();
obj.test();
```

**NOTE**

Follow proper Java Naming Conventions.

Class name should be `MyClass1`

Comment: -1: this is not true. Since myClass2 is not static, it has an implicit reference to an enclosing instance of myClass1, through which methods can be called.